# Change domain name of Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, dns, bluehost

Sorry about this seemingly basic question, but I have looked at the similar questions and those solutions (including Bluehost documentation) hasn't worked for me.

I have a Bluehost account hosting multiple add-on domains. Currently:

1. a.com > Existing wordpress site, located at `public_html/a`
2. b.com > Points to an empty directory at `public_html/b`

All I want to do is change my wordpress site from `a.com` to `b.com`.

I have read answers here, as well as other posts online, that suggest adding:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://b.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://b.com');
```

But of course that doesn't work. I don't see how that would work either since when I enter b.com, the server would be looking under folder b/ which is empty. I figure I'm just missing a simple step somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to be working for me so far:

1. In wordpress, under settings, change both Wordpress and Site URLs to `b.com`
2. After this, going to a.com/wp-admin won't work any more.
3. In bluehost, remove `public_html/b` and rename `public_html/a` to `public_html/b`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this tutorial?
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-your-wordpress-site-urls-step-by-step/

Also what I would suggest is to use something like the Better Search Replace plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ to scan your database and remove all references to domain "a.com" and replace it with "b.com"